# Creating users in 389 Directory Server: Autofill UID & GID

Tags: ldap, 389-ds

I have a **389 Directory Server** cluster as ldap.

I can create users using *389 management console* but...
When Selecting "*Posix User*" tab and checking "*Enable Posix User Attributes*" is necessary manually fill "*UID Number*" and "*GID Number*" fields.

Can be configure **389 Directory Server** to this fields be filled in automatic way?

Thanks.